# Django saving progress to the Session in subscript

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

So im wondering how this is done right.
I try to save the progress of a long running task inside the request.session object. And than be able to get the status of the process with another view method

Im using the Pool Class to make my long running progress async:

```
MyCalculation.py
def longrunning(x,request):
  request.session['status'] = 5;
  return x*x

views.py
def dolongrunning(request, x):
  pool = Pool(processes=1)
  result = pool.apply_async(MyCalculation.longrunning, [x, request])
  return JsonResponse(..)

def status(request):
  return JsonResponse(request.session.get('status))
```

so this doesnt work. My Async Job does executed but the request object doesnt get my progress informations.

How could i accomplish that or is there another way?
I have the feeling passing the request object is a bad idea in general.
What whould be a good practice to store the Status of a long running operation in Django/Python?

Comment: Please clarify better your question. What does not work? What are you trying to do?

Comment: okay updated my question. The updating of the request.session object doesnt work and im trying to store the progress of my long running operation somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different processes do not share the same memory space but they get a copy for each one of them.

In your case, the `request` object received by the worker process in the `longrunning` function is a copy of the one created in the parent process. Changes done on one of the processes do not affect the others.

What you want to do, is to send updates from the worker process to the parent one and then, within the parent one, update the request status.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue


def worker(task, message_queue):  # longrunning
    # do something
    message_queue.put(5)
    # do something else
    message_queue.put(42)


def request_handler(request, task, message_queue):  # dolongrunning
    result = pool.apply_async(worker, [task, message_queue])
    return JsonResponse(..)


def status(request):
    status = message_queue.get()  # this is blocking if no messages in queue
    request.session['status'] = status;
    return JsonResponse(request.session['status'])


pool = Pool(processes=1) 
message_queue = Queue()
```

This is quite simplified and it's actually blocking on status requests if no status is set but it gives an idea.

A better way would be storing the requests in a buffer and keeping the message queue empty with a thread. Each time a status request is received the last status update received from the workers would be returned.